# Java collection and MapKey

Tags: java

I am new to java.
I have a database table which have following composite key:

```
Code
Reference_Number_1 (decimal)
Reference_Number_2 (decimal)
Time
```

Above keys make each row a unique row  - no dupliactes. 
I need to create a class to load this table to a java collection and create a static method which will take above four arguments as key and return the entity from java collection.

I am thinking of loading the table into a HashMap but I am not sure how to define the MapKey. Should I convert Reference_Number_1, Reference_Number_2 and Time in to a string and then concatenate these four fields?
Or there is another way/collection to load this table.
Thanks,
Pete

Comment: Why not just concatenate the keys with a `+` sign and use it as key for hashmap, with the rest being the data associated with the key. It's the easiest solution that'll work - do you really need something more complex?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response. Yes that is teh easiest way to do but I was not sure if I could just combine String, decimal and Time as it is to generate a MapKey as String. Sure, will do that way. Thanks for your help. Peter

Comment: Be cautious, that technique is fraught with ambiguity.  Consider the following tuples for reference_number_1 and reference_number_2 and their respective concatenations:  (10,10) = "1010" and (101,0) = "1010".  Supposing Code and Time were the same for both of these examples, the keys would collide and one value would get overridden.

Comment: There's a reason "stringly typed code" is so badly frowned upon...

Answer (score 6):

Create another class which holds those 4 fields as properties and implement/autogenerate `equals()` and `hashCode()` [according the contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) (important! otherwise it can't be used as a proper `Map` key) and finally use it as (composite) key for the `Map`.

Here's what Eclipse has autogenerated for me (the `equals()` is open for improvement, it's somewhat verbose):

```
public class CompositeKey {

    private String code;
    private BigDecimal referenceNumber1;
    private BigDecimal referenceNumber2;
    private Date time;

    public CompositeKey(String code, BigDecimal referenceNumber1, BigDecimal referenceNumber2, Date time) {
        this.code = code;
        this.referenceNumber1 = referenceNumber1;
        this.referenceNumber2 = referenceNumber2;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public BigDecimal getReferenceNumber1() {
        return referenceNumber1;
    }

    public BigDecimal getReferenceNumber2() {
        return referenceNumber2;
    }

    public Date getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        CompositeKey other = (CompositeKey) obj;
        if (code == null) {
            if (other.code != null)
                return false;
        }
        else if (!code.equals(other.code))
            return false;
        if (referenceNumber1 == null) {
            if (other.referenceNumber1 != null)
                return false;
        }
        else if (!referenceNumber1.equals(other.referenceNumber1))
            return false;
        if (referenceNumber2 == null) {
            if (other.referenceNumber2 != null)
                return false;
        }
        else if (!referenceNumber2.equals(other.referenceNumber2))
            return false;
        if (time == null) {
            if (other.time != null)
                return false;
        }
        else if (!time.equals(other.time))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((code == null) ? 0 : code.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((referenceNumber1 == null) ? 0 : referenceNumber1.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((referenceNumber2 == null) ? 0 : referenceNumber2.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((time == null) ? 0 : time.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I would like to try both but want to understand what is the difference if I concatenate those four fields and create a key for the HashMap or do the way you have suggested.

Comment: Better abstraction, improved readability and maintainability.  Using the string is _ridiculously_ fragile and bad practice.

Comment: @Peter read my comment in your original post to see an example of where the concatenation technique could go very wrong.

Comment: @BalusC, Louis Wasserman and jkschneider All thanks for your response. It it now clear to me. jkschneider, yes your example makes it very clear how concatenation may go wrong. BalusC, you are so quick and fast. Amazing. Thanks all for all your help. Peter

Comment: Note: if you happen to use JPA and Eclipse for Java EE, then you can even autogenerate complete entities from tables in a few clicks, assuming that the datamodel is properly designed with keys and all on em. It'll where necessary also autogenerate proper composite keys like above.

Answer (score 2):

Encapsulate these four fields in an object:

```
public class Key {
    String code;
    float reference1;
    float reference2;
    Date time;

    public Key(String code, float ref1, float ref2, Date time) {
        ...
    }

    // implement equals() and hashCode()
}
```

Then define a `Map` as follows (not sure what type the "entity" is, so we will just pretend there is a class called `Entity`:

`Map<Key, Entity> lookup = new HashMap<Key, Entity>();`